# How to extract data from a list with a for loop

Tags: python, list, text, extract

I have a list with numerical data. Numbers are separated with a dot "." and a space " " unless they are negative, in which case the space " " is replaced by the negative sign "-".

I've been having trouble getting out all of the information, which should fit in a 2982x16 matrix, because the numbers are not separated in the same fashion.

Part of the list is something like this:

`1. 1.3884e-17. 0.0000e+00. 1.1913e+00. 1.3996e+00.-7.7122e-01.-1.8788e-01.-5.3170e-16. 1.0076e-31. 0.0000e+00. 3.9673e+05.-1.9531e+05.-3.6224e+04.-7.2504e-11. 1.3740e-26. 0.0000e+00`

`2. 1.3573e-17. 7.3889e-02. 1.3726e+00. 1.6331e+00. 1.2526e+00. 1.5132e+00.-1.3979e-16.-5.3936e-32.-2.9361e-16. 5.9535e+05. 4.9158e+05. 5.6265e+05.-1.9062e-11.-7.3549e-27.-4.0038e-11`

So far, I've only been able to extract the first two columns with something like this:

```
mat[i,1]=ast.literal_eval(line[3+k:13+k].replace(" ",""))
```

with the first piece aimed at converting text into float and the last part aimed at eliminating a space in the text. In this case, the number '1.3884e-17' and '1.3573e-17' would be placed in the second column of my matrix, but this doesn't really work for the following, of course changing the indices of the list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this would be a good use of regex, i think. have you tried using a regex to parse our your numbers?

Comment: It looks like your data has a *row number* at the beginning of each *line* (`1.` and `2.`).  Do you want that included in the result?

Answer (score 3):

```
s = '1. 1.3884e-17. 0.0000e+00. 1.1913e+00. 1.3996e+00.-7.7122e-01.-1.8788e-01.-5.3170e-16. 1.0076e-31. 0.0000e+00. 3.9673e+05.-1.9531e+05.-3.6224e+04.-7.2504e-11. 1.3740e-26. 0.0000e+00'
```

The numbers are separated by `.` followed by either a space or dash.  Use a regular expression to match that separator and split the string on it.  The pattern needs to use a *lookahead assertion* to prevent consuming the negative sign.

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'[.](?=[ -])'
>>> re.split(pattern, s)
['1', ' 1.3884e-17', ' 0.0000e+00', ' 1.1913e+00', ' 1.3996e+00', '-7.7122e-01', '-1.8788e-01', '-5.3170e-16', ' 1.0076e-31', ' 0.0000e+00', ' 3.9673e+05', '-1.9531e+05', '-3.6224e+04', '-7.2504e-11', ' 1.3740e-26', ' 0.0000e+00']
```

Make each  number a float

```
>>> [float(n) for n in re.split(pattern, s)]
[1.0, 1.3884e-17, 0.0, 1.1913, 1.3996, -0.77122, -0.18788, -5.317e-16, 1.0076e-31, 0.0, 396730.0, -195310.0, -36224.0, -7.2504e-11, 1.374e-26, 0.0]
>>>
```

---

If the first *number* of each line is not needed, use a slice to exclude it:

```
>>> numbers = re.split(pattern, s)
>>> [float(n) for n in numbers[1:]]
[1.3884e-17, 0.0, 1.1913, 1.3996, -0.77122, -0.18788, -5.317e-16, 1.0076e-31, 0.0, 396730.0, -195310.0, -36224.0, -7.2504e-11, 1.374e-26, 0.0]
>>>
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to exclude the first number. It seems to be an index. See  `[3+k:13+k]` in his post.

Comment: I must have been confused by the spec that it should fit in a m by 16 matrix.  That first _number_ did look like a row number.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `re.findall()` to match every number.

This expression should work: `-?\d+\.\d+e[+-]\d+`

- `-?` - Optional minus sign
- `\d+` - sequence of digits, i.e. the whole part of the significand
- `\.` - literal period
- `\d+` - the fractional part of the significand
- `e[+-]` - literal "e" followed by sign of the exponent
- `\d+` - the exponent

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import pprint

string_data = '''1. 1.3884e-17. 0.0000e+00. 1.1913e+00. 1.3996e+00.-7.7122e-01.-1.8788e-01.-5.3170e-16. 1.0076e-31. 0.0000e+00. 3.9673e+05.-1.9531e+05.-3.6224e+04.-7.2504e-11. 1.3740e-26. 0.0000e+00
2. 1.3573e-17. 7.3889e-02. 1.3726e+00. 1.6331e+00. 1.2526e+00. 1.5132e+00.-1.3979e-16.-5.3936e-32.-2.9361e-16. 5.9535e+05. 4.9158e+05. 5.6265e+05.-1.9062e-11.-7.3549e-27.-4.0038e-11
'''
data = [
    [
        float(number) for number in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.\d+e[+-]\d+', line)
    ]
    for line in string_data.splitlines()
]

pprint.pprint(data)
```

Comment: Do you like this because it *positively* matches each number instead of relying on the aftermath of splitting the string?

Comment: Yes. It matches my internal sense: I'm identifying the thing of value rather than identifying the material in which it's packed.